# Issue with async value for React context not available from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to consume a **React context** that is populated from a js promise.

The issue I have is that the child component consuming the context (i.e. `AnotherPage`) is rendered before the value from the context is available from the `useEffect` called in the root `App` page. So that if I try to access one of the context properties, I will get an error since it is `undefined/null`.

How can I refactor/redesign my app so that the context is available from the child component?

Here is the code for my app:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createContext, useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const MyContext = createContext(null);

export default function App() {
  console.log('App');

  const [myObj, setMyObj] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve({ id: 42, text: 'some value from promise' }).then((res) => {
      console.log('resolved: ', res);
      setMyObj(res);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={myObj}>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
        <AnotherPage />
      </div>
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

const AnotherPage = () => {
  console.log('AnotherPage');

  const obj = useContext(MyContext);
  console.log('myObj', obj);// undefined/null at first page render...

  return <div>Hello from another page</div>;
};
```

Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xkxhxk?file=src/App.js

FYI, in my real app the actual object resolved from a promise is much more complex that the `myObj` below.

Comment: Add a condition beforehand, it always will be null on first render. `{myObj && <AnotherPage />` or at the component itself.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. The issue is that in my **real app's** child component, there are many `useCallbacks` and other logic that depend on the object before the component is rendered. So I have to repeat lots of **if conditions** in the component which makes it ugly and difficult to test...

Comment: You dont need to repeat, put the condition on the provider not for every consumer...

Comment: That sounds interesting. Can you expound on that please? With a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't escape it, you must check nullability somewhere:

1. Within every consumer (`useContext`) user, the easiest way is to write a custom hook and check for nullability there.
2. Or, within the provider itself, conditionally render children

Notice that it isn't a "first render" problem since its a promise, you can delay it for enough time that it will update after the first render.

```
export default function App() {
  const [myObj, setMyObj] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve({ id: 42, text: 'some value from promise' }).then((res) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setMyObj(res);
      }, 2000);
    });
  }, []);

  const children = useMemo(
    () => (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
        <AnotherPage />
      </div>
    ),
    []
  );

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={myObj}>{myObj && children}</MyContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a4s9yr?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a loader until the promise resolves.
Such that the child components doesn't even get rendered before the promise resolves.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createContext, useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const MyContext = createContext(null);

export default function App() {
  console.log('App');

  const [myObj, setMyObj] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve({ id: 42, text: 'some value from promise' }).then((res) => {
      console.log('resolved: ', res);
      setMyObj(res);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={myObj}>
      {
        myObj ? <div>
          <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
          <AnotherPage />
        </div> : <div>Loading....</div>
      }
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

const AnotherPage = () => {
  console.log('AnotherPage');

  const obj = useContext(MyContext);
  console.log('myObj', obj);// undefined/null at first page render...

  return <div>Hello from another page</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the Context with some *temporary value* instead of **null**.

Instead of Doing

```js
const MyContext = createContext(null);
```

Do

```js
const MyContext = createContext({id: -1, text: 'yet to be initialized'});
```

So you child component will consume this values until the promise updates the context value.

Comment: The actual object used in my real app is much more complex than that actually. It is not feasible and even impossible to initialize all of its methods and properties...

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this:

```
const ASYNC_STATUS = {
  Idle: 'idle',
  Pending: 'pending',
  Success: 'success',
  Failed: 'failed',
};

export default function App() {
  console.log('App');

  const [myObj, setMyObj] = useState({
    value: null,
    status: ASYNC_STATUS.Idle,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      setMyObj((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        status: ASYNC_STATUS.Pending,
      }));
      Promise.resolve({ id: 42, text: 'some value from promise' }).then(
        (res) => {
          console.log('resolved: ', res);
          setMyObj({
            value: res,
            status: ASYNC_STATUS.Success,
          });
        }
      );
    } catch {
      setMyObj((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        status: ASYNC_STATUS.Success,
      }));
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={myObj}>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
        <AnotherPage />
      </div>
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

const AnotherPage = () => {
  console.log('AnotherPage');

  const { value, status } = useContext(MyContext);
  console.log('myObj', value);

  return (
    <div>
      {status === ASYNC_STATUS.Pending && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {status === ASYNC_STATUS.Failed && <div>Failed!</div>}
      {status === ASYNC_STATUS.Success && value && <div>here what you want to show</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks Raman, See my above comment to Denis. Much of the logic in my real app's child component depends on a very complex object so that using conditions would make my component quite ugly...