# How do I make React UseContext wait for a value instead of returning undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have the below:

```js
  const {totals} = useMyContext();
```

totals definetely exists on the object but at the time when useMyContext() is called it must not be there yet. Hence undefined.

The coding is breaking on the above line. I am not sure how best to make the below wait until the totals has a value which is not undefined.

```js
return( 
<div>{totals?.foo}</div> 
)
```

Comment: `return( { totals && totals.foo && <div>{totals?.foo}</div>}`    then handle totals in useEffect or setState

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70710995/issue-with-async-value-for-react-context-not-available-from-child-component Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for the response @BryanDellinger the problem is it won't get to the line of code you mentioned because it breaks beforehand at const {totals} = useMyContext();

Comment: is useMyContext() asynchronous? do you need to await it, or handle the promise?

Comment: @BryanDellinger no it's not async. I think the context isn't loaded when component is rendered

Comment: You'd better provide more context or replicate the relevant code in codesandbox

Comment: @Ry2254 this sounds like this component is not inside of a Context Provider for this context. And are you sure that the context provider has a value right from the start?

Answer (score 0):

I am used to Redux wrapping the entire App. I discovered this is not the case with useContext. totals had no value as it was not wrapped in the context. Silly mistake.